# Speeding Up sequential Puts in Java TreeMap

Tags: java, performance, treemap

In an application I am working on at the moment, one of the one of the most time consuming functions is the `put()` operation in a `TreeMap` (~30% of the runtime).

Often these calls to `put()` are invoked sequentially from another function, so the `put()` function calls will be with ordered keys. This will of course lead to a lot of rebalancing in the RB-Tree, which contributes to the runtime.

Is there any (easy) way to speedup my application?

Comment: Do you have to use a `TreeMap`? A `HashMap` is in many cases an order of magnitude faster, because it has an average insertion time of *O(1)*.

Comment: What's the key type?

Comment: Yes it has to be a TreeMap, especially floor/ceilingEntry and floor/ceilingKey are important.

Keys are Longs

Comment: If you're storing boxed Longs in your map, then the easiest way to improve performance is to change to a specialized collection. I wasn't able to find a library that implements a TreeMap specialized for primitive types, but it shouldn't be too hard to roll your own.

Comment: Yes, I've already searched for that but only found primitive implementations (Colt, Trove for example) for normal Maps, not SortedMaps.

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt at optimisation should be to switch to a [ConcurrentSkipListMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html). Although this may make no difference and might even make things slower it should be worth trying as it is the only other 'Map' that implements 'SortedMap' (presumably the reason for using 'TreeMap'.

After that you are looking for a special custom implementation of 'Map' that is faster at adding sorted new entries..

Comment: I just tried that, and it lead to about a ~20% increase in runtime. Will now try to look for custom implementations.